# Orientation configuration for different layouts android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, orientation

I have two layouts for my potrait and landscape modes.

In potrait I have a ListView and in Landscape I have a GridView.

layout/myxml.xml

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/getdata" 
     android:divider="#b5b5b5"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

layout-land/myxml.xml

```
 <com.etsy.android.grid.StaggeredGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/grid_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:item_margin="8dp"
app:column_count="3" />
```

Iam inflating these layouts in my class which extends a Fragment. I want to inflate both views depending on the orientation.

This is what I do:-

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        Configuration config;

        if(config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)
        {
        View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myxml, container, false);
newsList = (ListView)vi.findViewById(android.R.id.list); //Error Here

 itemsAdapter = new LazyAdapter(myContext, getList );
 newsList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        }
        else if(config.orientation ==Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
        {
            View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myxml, container, false);
                       mGridView =(StaggeredGridView)vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
                        stagAdaper = new StaggeredAdapter(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getList);
           mGridView.setAdapter(stagAdaper);
        }
}
```

But I get an error:-

```
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-09 10:44:34.369: E/AndroidRuntime(2680):     at mypackage.class(HomeFragment.java:220)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `Configuration config;` is null because you did not instantiate it.

Another way to find if you are `landscape` or `portrait` mode is to instantiate `StaggeredGridView` and `ListView` and check if one of them is null.

**example:**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myxml, container, false);
    newsList = (ListView) vi.findViewById(android.R.id.list); // Error Here
    mGridView = (StaggeredGridView) vi.findViewById(R.id.grid_view);

    if (mGridView == null) {
        itemsAdapter = new LazyAdapter(myContext, getList);
        newsList.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
    } else {
        stagAdaper = new StaggeredAdapter(myContext,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getList);
        mGridView.setAdapter(stagAdaper);
    }

}
```

**about:**

What the above code is doing is that it checks if `mGridView` is null, if it is then you are currently `portrait` mode else you are in `landscape` mode

Answer (score 0):

Here you didn't initiate Configuration variable. Change the code like this:

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
..Your code for LANDSCAPE view ....
}else if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
..Your code for PORTRAIT view .....
}
```